# Restart-Computer : Failed to restart the computer with the following error message: A system shutdown is in progress

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I have installed updates on my Windows 2012r2 Machine and as usual, I did a reboot.
However, it seems that the machine has hung itself during the reboot process and does not do a proper shutdown.
I can initiate a connection via RDP, but not connect to the machine, I can also send commands via powershell, so I have tried sending a Force reboot:

```
Restart-Computer -Force -Credential domain\adminuser -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME
```

The reply from the server is the following:

```
Restart-Computer : Failed to restart the computer 10.250.35.16 with the following error message: A system shutdown is in progress.
```

Is there a way to force the reboot and kill the processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the System Event Notification Services was stuck, and killing it remotely did actually solve the issue:

```
pskill \\REMOTECOMPUTER svchost
```

First, I listed the running services on the remote machine:

```
tasklist /s remoteServer
```

Then I started to manually kill the processes with the above command.

Answer (score 3):

I found this helpful.

```
TASKKILL /S serverIP /U userid /P password /F /IM LSASS.EXE /T
TASKKILL /S serverIP /U userid /P password /F /IM WINLOGON.exe /T
```

Even when I couldn't connect to the machine with PSTools, I was still able to connect via WinRM using Enter-PSSession and execute these commands locally.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM LSASS.EXE /T
TASKKILL /F /IM WINLOGON.exe /T
```